# jQuery move table row's with inputs and change id/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I need to have buttons for moving up and down table rows with input's inside.
On move I need to guarantee that the input's name's and id's are changed
regarding to their new position

I've tried around on JSFiddle but couldn't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/vaDkF/1194/

For example I've the first row is moved down there are four changes:

```
        <input type="text" id="id_1" name="id_1"/>
        <input type="text" id="test_1" name="test_1"/>
```

needs to become

```
        <input type="text" id="id_2" name="id_2"/>
        <input type="text" id="test_2" name="test_2"/>
```

but the values need's to stay the same just need the id/name to change.

This is just a test example, in production environment I have like 20 inputs
per row.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: get the index of the row where you clicked using `$(this).parent().parent().index();` if up is clicked do `index++` else `index--` then replace the id and name of the controls as `var id = control.attr("id").split("_"); control.attr("id",id + "_"+index).attr("name",id + "_"+index);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : after rearranging the rows, call a function which will reassigne id and name to the input fields

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        if ($(this).is(".up")) {
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
        } else {
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
        }
        reAssignIdAndName();
    });

    reAssignIdAndName = function(){
        $('table tr').each(function(index){
            $(this).find('td:eq(2) input').each(function(){
            //id of input element
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            //get index of underscrore
            var underScoreIndex = id.indexOf('_');
            //take id till underscore and append your index+1 value
            id = id.substring(0,underScoreIndex+1)+(parseInt(index)+1);
            //assigne new id and name
            $(this).attr('id',id); 
            $(this).attr('name',id);                
            });
        });
    };
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/vaDkF/1203/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works and reAssign the position only for the 2 rows that moved :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        row = $this.parents("tr:first");

    if ($this.is(".up")) {
        if (row.parent().find("tr:first").get(0) !== row.get(0)) {
            reAssignPosition(row.prev().find('input'));
            row.insertBefore(row.prev());
            reAssignPosition(row.find('input'), true);
        }
    } else {
        if (row.parent().find("tr:last").get(0) !== row.get(0)) {
            reAssignPosition(row.next().find('input'), true);
            row.insertAfter(row.next());
            reAssignPosition(row.find('input'));
        }
    }
});

function reAssignPosition($elt, up) {
    var $row = $elt.parents("tr:first"),
        oldPosition = parseInt($row.find('input').attr('id').replace(/(id|test)_/, '')),
        newPosition, newId, newName, input = $row.find('input');    
    if (up) newPosition = oldPosition - 1;
    else newPosition = oldPosition + 1;
    $elt.each(function() {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/(id|test)_(.*)/, "$1_" + (newPosition));
        this.name = this.name.replace(/(id|test)_(.*)/, "$1_" + (newPosition));
    });
}
```

});

Some refactoring can be done, I am sure, though.